# lightning container issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

**CMP:**

```
    <aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<lightning:container src="{!$Resource.myApp + '/index.html'}"/> 
</aura:component>
```

**APP:**

```
    <aura:application >
<c:ReactContainerCmp /> 
</aura:application>
```

react component details:
**app.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
const tbheader=['Company','Contact','Country'];
const tbdata=['Alfreds Futterkiste','Maria Anders','Germany'];
/*const Tbhd = this.props.tbheader.map((tbh) =>
      <th>{tbh}</th>
  );
const Tbdd = this.props.tbdata.map((tbd) =>
      <td>{tbd}</td>
  ); */
return (
 <div>
<table>
<tr>
{tbheader}
</tr>
<tr>
{tbdata}
</tr>
</table>
</div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default App;

```
**index.js:**
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**index.html:**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run the react app local development server it is rendering the static table.When I zipped the build folder and upload as static resource in sales force and try to render in lightning container it is not rendering.

Comment: Can you check the browser console to see if you are getting any errors ??

Comment: Content Security Policy: Ignoring ‘x-frame-options’ because of ‘frame-ancestors’ directive.  (unknown)
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src or style-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified  (unknown)
Content Security Policy: Directive ‘frame-src’ has been deprecated. Please use directive ‘child-src’ instead.  (unknown)
a is undefined  mcafee_wa_bkground.js:30
Use of document.createAttribute() is deprecated. Use element.setAttribute() instead.  aura_prod.js:5:603
a is undefined  mcafee_wa_bkground.js:30

Comment: i disabled csp critical updates also.

Comment: Okay , is this the entire code ? or have you abstracted something ? Because there are multiple errors in console. The error "document.createAttribute()" is a locker service issue reference : https://tinyurl.com/yb3rrt6x  (ideally locker should not affect much of lightning:container as it was introduced to overcome issues with locker service) , For csp directives you might have to check the references to index.html . And we have a known issue for lightning:container when used inside a lightning component , as you have reference : https://tinyurl.com/ycpjf64m .

Comment: yes it is entire code.if you have react app you can apply in app.js,index.js and index.html and try to see.or you need full build folder?

Comment: Do *not* use flags to request an answer. Flags are meant to indicate inappropriate content only.

Comment: any update on this??

Comment: no updates on this